# How can I make "headings" inside a figure?

Tags: spacing, floats, sectioning, formatting

I have a figure that is built up of multiple parts and I want each part to have a "title". How can I do that in a way that looks nice? Right now I am just using `\textbf` for the "titles" and everything ends up mushed together:

[image: Figure with spaceless-headings]

This is a sample of the Latex I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \textbf{Syntax}

    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        Variable   & $x$ & ::= & $x,y,z,…$ \\
        Expression & $e$ & ::= & $x$ $|$ $(\lambda x.\,e)$ $|$ $(e_1\;e_2)$
    \end{tabular}

    \textbf{Free Variables} \fbox{$FV(e)$}

    \begin{align*}
        FV(x) & = \{x\} \\
        FV(\lambda x.\,e) & = FV(e) - \{x\} \\
        FV((e_1\;e_2)) & = FV(e_1) \cup FV(e_2)
    \end{align*}

    \caption{The lambda calculus}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I add some space around the "Syntax" and "Free Variables" so things don't look so crowded? Is there a more "semantic" way to create "figure subsections" (like h1, h2, etc in html) or should I format my figure by hand with explicit spacing commands?

Comment: This isn't relly a figure, right? You can define new float types using `tocbasic` or `newfloat` etc. Another helpful tool for such example boxes (for a lack of a better name now) is `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Also use semantic commands (like section) instead of formatting stuff directly. for example `\newcommand{\keyline}[1]{\textbf{#1}\par}`. Something to prevent a pagebreak after the keyline would also be needed.

Comment: @Johannes_B: What name do you think would be better than "Figure" here? I also checked a textbook right now and they also use "Figure" for this kind of stuff

Comment: Personally, i would use figure for something that contains a figure/diagra/image. Similar for tables, i would use table. I can't suggest a better name though.

Answer (score 2):

There should be other ways of doing this, but if I were you, I would have chosen the sectioning commands. The obvious advantages are,

1. Automatics fonts.
2. Rubber length inter-spaces.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}
     \section*{Syntax}

     \begin{tabular}{llll}
         Variable   & $x$ & ::= & $x,y,z,…$ \\
         Expression & $e$ & ::= & $x$ $|$ $(\lambda x.\,e)$ $|$ $(e_1\;e_2)$
     \end{tabular}

   \subsection*{Free Variables \fbox{$FV(e)$}}

   \begin{align*}
       FV(x) & = \{x\} \\
       FV(\lambda x.\,e) & = FV(e) - \{x\} \\
       FV((e_1\;e_2)) & = FV(e_1) \cup FV(e_2)
   \end{align*}

   \caption{The lambda calculus}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: I didn't know you could actually use `\section` and `\subsection` inside figures. It sounds obvious in hindsight though.

Comment: @hugomg Neither did I. I was rather surprised when it worked. (If the solution suits your purpose, you can accept it as well :-). Or you can adopt my policy of waiting for a couple days before accepting, to see whether a better one turns up.)

Comment: yeah, I always wait a bit before accepting. It also allows answers to get more upvotes.